# Ideal settings for pgbouncer with Django's CONN_MAX_AGE

Tags: django, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

I'm running a multi-tennant website, where I would like to reduce the overhead of creating a PostgreSQL connection per request. Django's CONN_MAX_AGE allows this, at the expense of creating a lot of open idle connections to PostgreSQL (8 workers * 20 threads = 160 connections). With 10MB per connection, this consumes a lot of memory.

The main purpose is reducing connection-time overhead.
Hence my questions:

- Which setup should I use for such solution? (PgBouncer?)
- Can I use 'transaction' pool mode with Django?
- Would I be better off using something like: https://github.com/kennethreitz/django-postgrespool instead of Django's pooling?

Django 1.6 settings:

```
DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

     ....

    'PORT': '6432'
    'OPTIONS': {'autocommit': True,},
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 300,
}

ATOMIC_REQUESTS = False   # default
```

Postgres:

```
max_connections = 100
```

PgBouncer:

```
pool_mode = session     # Can this be transaction?
max_client_conn = 400   # Should this match postgres max_connections?
default_pool_size = 20
reserve_pool_size = 5
```

Comment: Can you please update what did you do finally ?

Comment: `max_client_conn` - no it shouldn't match the postgres settings. `pgbouncer` should accept that many connections, which will wait in the pool to be processed, when the pgbouncer real database connections are freed/unused

Answer (score 19):

Here's a setup I've used.

pgbouncer running on same machine as gunicorn, celery, etc.

pgbouncer.ini:

```
[databases]
<dbname> = host=<dbhost> port=<dbport> dbname=<dbname>

[pgbouncer]
: your app will need filesystem permissions to this unix socket
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql
; you'll need to configure this file with username/password pairs you plan on
; connecting with.
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt

; "session" resulted in atrocious performance for us. I think
; "statement" prevents transactions from working.
pool_mode = transaction

; you'll probably want to change default_pool_size. take the max number of
; connections for your postgresql server, and divide that by the number of
; pgbouncer instances that will be conecting to it, then subtract a few
; connections so you can still connect to PG as an admin if something goes wrong.
; you may then need to adjust min_pool_size and reserve_pool_size accordingly.
default_pool_size = 50
min_pool_size = 10
reserve_pool_size = 10
reserve_pool_timeout = 2
; I was using gunicorn + eventlet, which is why this is so high. It
; needs to be high enough to accommodate all the persistent connections we're
; going to allow from Django & other apps.
max_client_conn = 1000
...
```

/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt:

```
"<dbuser>" "<dbpassword>"
```

Django settings.py:

```
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<dbname>',
        'USER': '<dbuser>',
        'PASSWORD': '<dbpassword>',
        'HOST': '/var/run/postgresql',
        'PORT': '',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': None,  # Set to None for persistent connections
    }
}
...
```

If I remember correctly, you can basically have any number of "persistent" connections to pgbouncer, since pgbouncer releases server connections back to the pool when Django is done with them (as long as you're using `transaction` or `statement` for `pool_mode`). When Django tries to reuse its persistent connection, pgbouncer takes care of waiting for a usable connection to Postgres.

Comment: I also found this explanation which was pretty helpful: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.postgresql.pgbouncer.general/979

Comment: The hardest part about using pgbouncer is figuring out which settings are for PG and which are for pgbouncer. They really ought to be prefixed or something.

Comment: What about the second question?

> Can I use 'transaction' pool mode with Django?

Comment: Yes, it's used in my example config. `pool_mode = transaction`

Comment: I wasn't able to run "HOST" as "/var/run/postgresql" - I set it to the port pgbouncer was listening on (localhost, port 6432). Is this a typo in your response @SeánHayes  or am I misunderstanding something? TY for the response - very helpful.

Comment: In pgbouncer.ini I have `unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql`, so in this setup PG Bouncer is using a unix socket.

Comment: @SeánHayes: how would you tweak your settings.py configuration if pgbouncer was installed on the application server and the db server was separate?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to connect to Postgres using a unix socket, you'd need to use IP:port, so that would need to be specified in pgbouncer.ini under `[databases]`. Also look at my comment about changing `default_pool_size`. You can still connect to pgbouncer using a unix socket as long as it's on the same machine, however if pgbouncer is running on a different machine you'll need to use IP:port in settings.py.

Comment: Under `[databases]`, I have `db1 = host=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=db1`, i.e. host IP and port are both specified like you said. In settings.py, I'm currently running with this: `DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://user1:pass1@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432/db1'`. What's your opinion on configuration like this?

Comment: You need your Django settings to point to wherever pgbouncer is. The settings you describe will simply point to the same PG instance as pgbouncer, thereby bypassing it. Also, `DATABASE_URL` isn't a setting supported by Django AFAIK, I assume you're using some code to translate that into a standard `DATABASES` `dict`?

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm not using `DATABASE_URL` as a setting. I actually set up my problem as a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248970/django-settings-when-using-pgbouncer Could you give it a quick skim?