# django, pgBouncer and CONN_MAX_AGE

Tags: django, postgresql, pgbouncer

Similar but unanswered question [Ideal settings for pgbouncer with Django's CONN_MAX_AGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418264/ideal-settings-for-pgbouncer-with-djangos-conn-max-age)

I wonder if using both is really beneficial, or should we use only one of them?

Comment: If you currently don't have a performance problem, you should use neither

Comment: I see the same page sometimes slow and sometimes ok, I am guessing it might be due to creating connection.

Comment: @Andomar: btw, thanks for the DB course link in your profile. I'll definately check it out.

Comment: Do you find the answer?